# Can a stack allocated Rust buffer be accessed through C++?

Tags: c++, rust

In order to avoid head allocations, and since I know the maximum MTU of an ethernet packet, I created a small `buffer: [u8, MAX_BYTES_TRANSPORT]` in Rust, that C++ should fill for me:

```
pub fn receive(&mut self, f: &dyn Fn(&[u8])) -> std::result::Result<(), &str> {
    let mut buffer: [u8; MAX_BYTES_TRANSPORT] = [0; MAX_BYTES_TRANSPORT];
    //number of bytes written in buffer in the C++ side
    let written_size: *mut size_t = std::ptr::null_mut::<size_t>();
    let r = unsafe{openvpn_client_receive_just(
        buffer.as_mut_ptr(), buffer.len(), written_size, self.openvpn_client)};
```

So, the function `openvpn_client_receive_just`, which is a C++ function with C interface, should write to this buffer. Is this safe? I couldn't find information about a stack allocated Rust buffer being used in C++

This is the function:

```
uint8_t openvpn_client_receive_just(
    uint8_t *buffer, size_t buffer_size, size_t *written_size, OpenVPNSocket *client)
```

Comment: In Rust lingo calling any C/C++ function is equally "unsafe". That being said passing pointers to stack-allocated buffers is more dangerous in general since buffer overruns on the stack can usually be much more easily exploited.

Comment: Note: you may need to be careful about [Jumbo frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can a stack allocated buffer be accessed through C++?

**Yes**.

From the type-system perspective there is no difference between statically allocated, stack allocated, or heap allocated: the C signature only takes pointer and size, and cares little where that pointer points to.

> Is this safe?

**Most likely**.

As long as the C function is correctly written and respects the bounds of the buffer, this will be safe. If it doesn't, well, that's a bug.

One could argue that it's better to have a heap-allocated buffer, but honestly once one starts writing out of bounds, overwriting arbitrary stack bytes or overwriting arbitrary heap bytes are both *bad*, and have undefined behavior.

For extra security, you *could* use a heap allocated nested between 2 guard pages. Using OS specific facilities, you could allocate 3 contiguous OS pages (typically 4KB each on x86), then mark the first and last as read-only and put your buffer in the middle one. Then any (close) write before or after the buffer would be caught by the OS. Larger jumps, though, wouldn't... so it's a lot of effort for a mitigation.

> Is *your code* safe?

You most likely need to know how many bytes were written, so using a null pointer is strange.

I'd expect to see:

```
let mut written: size_t = 0;
let written_size = &mut written as *mut _;
```

And yes, that's once again a pointer to a stack variable, just like you would in C.

---

A note on style. Your Rust code is unusual in that you use fully typed variables and full paths, a more idiomatic style would be:

```
// Result is implicitly in scope.

pub fn receive(&mut self, f: &dyn Fn(&[u8])) -> Result<(), &str) {
    let mut buffer = [0u8; MAX_BYTES_TRANSPORT];

    let mut written: size_t = 0;
    let written_size = &mut written as *mut _;

    //  Safety:
    //  <enumerate preconditions to safely call the function here, and why they are met>
    let result = unsafe {
        openvpn_client_receive_just(
            buffer.as_mut_ptr(), buffer.len(), written_size, self.openvpn_client)
    };

    translate_openvpn_error(result)?;

    let buffer = &buffer[0..written];
    f(buffer);

    Ok(())
}
```

I did annotate the type for `written`, to help along inference, but strictly speaking it should not be necessary.

Also, I like to preface every unsafe call I make with the list of pre-conditions that make it safe, and for each why they are met. It helps me audit my unsafe code later on.